# produce error output for only once

Tags: java, authentication, reader

i've started learning java recently and i am intended to create a login system with validation from text files. The image shows what i intended to do with the login validation. 
[Intending flow of operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSY4z.jpg)

```
BufferedReader bra = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Admin.txt"));
int num = typebox.getSelectedIndex();
switch (num)
{
   case 0: while ((reader = bra.readLine()) != null)
   {
       String[] split0 = reader.split("\\s");
       User admin = new User();
       admin.username = nametextbox.getText();
       admin.password = passtextbox.getText();

       \\login verification               
       if (admin.username.equals(split0[0]) && admin.password.equals(split0[1]))
       {
            bra.close();
            A_Selection puff = new A_Selection();
            puff.pack();
            puff.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            puff.setVisible(true);
       }
       else
       {
            bra.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, wrong username or password!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } 
   }
}
break;
```

However, it tends to repeats the error part until the number of lines in the text file finishes. Is there any way to make the system produce error output only once after reading the whole file?

Comment: put the call of the `showMessageDialog` behind the `while ((reader = bra.readLine()) != null) { ...} ` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: 
I've figured it out, with the help of declaring another variable and if condition.

```
int flag = 0; 
if (admin.username.equals(split0[0] && admin.password.equals(split0[1]))
{
    flag = 1;
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        A_Selection puff = new A_Selection();
        puff.pack();
        puff.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        puff.setVisible(true);
    }
}
\\outside while loop
if (flag == 0)
{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**break** should work.

```
...
else
{
   bra.close();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, wrong username or password!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   break;
} 
...
```